# Modifying tcp_options and tcp_options_seq

Tags: linux, tcp, packet, sysctl

I was trying to modify tcp options parameters using sysctl, but nothing seems to work.
for example:

mac machine has following tcp_options seq:
mss,nop,ws,nop,nop,ts,sok,eol,eol

windows has:
mss,nop,ws,nop,nop,sok

linux has:
mss,sok,ts,nop,ws

how can we convert linux kernel params to make the tcp_options look like mac or windows?